# Silverlight ListBox throws out of range exception when changing SelectedItem

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm

I have some Silverlight XAML that used to work, but I can't seem to figure out what I did to suddenly make it stop working, or even how to change it.

Here's some XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsForSelectedPublisher}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemForPublisher, Mode=TwoWay}"
         DisplayMemberPath="ItemNameWithSelectionCount"
         SelectionMode="Single"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
         FontSize="14" 
         Width="300" 
         Height="500"
         />
```

And some code from the view model:

```
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> ItemsForSelectedPublisher
    {
        get { return _itemsForSelectedPublisher; }
        private set
        {
            if (_itemsForSelectedPublisher != value)
            {
                _itemsForSelectedPublisher = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => ItemsForSelectedPublisher);
            }
        }
    }

    public ItemViewModel SelectedItemForPublisher
    {
        get { return _selectedItemForPublisher; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedItemForPublisher != value)
            {
                _selectedItemForPublisher = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedItemForPublisher);
            }
        }
    }
```

After the ListBox's SelectedItem is changed (set for the first time), the following exception gets caught in the Silverlight Application.UnhandledException Handler.

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.SelectorAutomationPeer.RaiseSelectionEvents(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.InvokeSelectionChanged(List`1 unselectedItems, List`1 selectedItems)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.End()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.SelectJustThisItem(Int32 oldIndex, Int32 newIndex)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ListBox.MakeSingleSelection(Int32 index)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ListBox.HandleItemSelection(ListBoxItem item, Boolean isMouseSelection)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ListBox.OnListBoxItemClicked(ListBoxItem item)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(Control ctrl, EventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName, UInt32 flags)
```

From what I can tell, the ListBox is getting some incorrect index but no idea what it is or why that's even happening. Anyone have an idea how this could be happening? At this point I don't know where else to look.

Comment: Can you please provide a little more info or code for this.

Comment: Can you post the code for your ItemViewModel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research I found the root cause was my own fault (no real surprise there). Apparently the bug in my own code was in an incorrect Equals() override for some of my view models. This caused the ListBox binding to go haywire and throw the out of range exceptions.